# Prime number checker

Tags: loops, python-2.7

I had to develop a program using python that takes as input a series of positive integers and output whether each is a prime number. The program should terminate if a negative number is given as an input and that number should be printed. One is not a prime number. The thin is my program doesn't run when I input a negative number and it gives one as a prime.

```
num=int(input('Enter:'))
for num in range (1,num+1):
 for i in range(2,num):
        if (num%i==0 or num==1):
            print num
            break;

 else:
        print num, "is a prime number"
```

Comment: Hint: Where are you checking if its a negative number?

Comment: Tag the question with the programming language you are using please.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid That's one problem I'm having. I don't know where to put that code.

Comment: Look at your problem statement _"The program should terminate if a negative number is given"_. You can read this another way "before you do anything else, check if the number is negative, if it is, quit". This should help you understand where to put that check.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid thank you very much. It did work. But I'm still having the problem of number one being a prime.

Comment: Just filter 1 out of your loop?

Answer (score 0):

This checks for negatives, and also checks for primes much faster then looping

```
import sys
import math


def check_prime(number):
    if (math.factorial(int(number) - 1) + 1)%int(number) == 0:
        print "Number is prime"
    else:
        print "Not Prime"

number = raw_input("Choose a positive integer")

if not number.isdigit() or number < 1:
    sys.exit()
else:
    check_prime(number)
```

Comment: Wilson's theorem is not really practical for testing for primes unless the number is tiny.